# Can LaTeX-TeX be described with EBNF grammar?

Tags: tex-core

This question is related to the question I asked here [How does a TeX engine process the informations within a .tex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648922/how-does-a-tex-engine-process-the-informations-within-a-tex-file). I want to write a program to parse TeX-LaTeX files. I found libraries to write parser that allow users to describe the langage they target with EBNF grammar.

**Can LaTeX-TeX be described with EBNF standard ?**

Comment: No. ------------

Comment: No try this valid plain tex file as a test case http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/xii/xii.tex

Comment: Note that tex itself at no point parses a tex document to any kind of parse tree. It simply processes the input character by character with reading input characters and evaluation of commands completely inter-mingled

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes I read that, but I thought I could intercept this process

Comment: @Elyo you can not even get a lexical analysis into tokens, far less a parse tree without a full tex typesetting engine  `aaa \ifnum\time>600 \catcode\`\%=12 \fi % is this a comment`  for example is or is not a comment depending on the time of day. You can specify a tex-like language grammar and parse that, but not parse arbitrary tex input

Comment: Well, you *can* get a lexical analysis into tokens in general case but that requires modifying the TeX program to output that content. As I mentioned before in most cases what you want to do is to make your program parse a "small" supported subset of LaTeX. For things like "what are the arguments this function take" it's complex... (learn TeX programming for more details.)